# How to add file transfer plugin in ionic framework?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, plugins, ionic-framework

Hi I am working on a project in that I need to download some file so I installed the file transfer plugin

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file and
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer
```

every thing is working fine in ios version

but when I tried to run the app in android it shows an error and not working the app

> BUILD FAILED
>
> /Users/munr/Documents/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:720: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   /Users/muar/Documents/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:734: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
>
> Total time: 4 seconds
>
> /Users/muar/androidtest/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
>                       throw e;
>                             ^
>   Error code 1 for command: ant with args: debug,-f,/Users/mur/androidtest/platforms/android/build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
>   Error: /Users/mvar/androidtest/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 8
>       at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
>       at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)

Comment: Are these all the errors? Or is some missing here? Can't see what is wrong from these errors.

Comment: this is the error coming whilebi am try to emulate or build android

Answer (score 0):

Try installing an SDK like Android 17 of 19. It's found in the tool manager.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other here you can download the SDK. Open the tool manager, select an android version and download every file associated with it. Basically check all the checkboxes. When done installing you will have installed an Android version. Next up in the tool manager go to devices, create an emulator (android device) with your newly installed android version, after creating run it. Wait for it to boot up and then try to build (read: run) for Android.